# Put method via JS (ajax) - backend returns badRequest (invalid model) / C#/WebAPI/MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

i have following problem: 
i have working PUT method inside my MVC controller

```
[HttpPut, Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody]Student student)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        using (var ctx = new EfDbContext())
        {
            student.Id = id;
            ctx.Students.Attach(student);
            var dbEntry = ctx.Entry(student);
            dbEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            if (student.Grades != null)
            {
                foreach (var grade in student.Grades)
                {
                    ctx.Grades.Attach(grade);
                    var entry = ctx.Entry(grade);
                    entry.State = grade.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added :
                        EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

i also have my javascript working with HTML form on the localhost website.

```
function addStudent() {
console.log($("#newStudent").serializeArray())
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:56658/api/api/students',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $("#newStudent").serializeArray(),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#students').append(listItem(data));
    }
});
```

}

and my editStudent script (here is the problem)

```
function editStudent(id) {
console.log($("#newStudent").serializeArray())
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:56658/api/api/students/' + id,
    type: 'put',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { id: id,student: $("#newStudent").serializeArray() },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#students').append(listItem(data));
    }
});
```

}

As you can see, i have two nearly identical scripts. Now, the problem is with editStudent - my backend returns badrequest as soon as i press submit button on web (having all text fields filled with valid data). Add student works just fine (im also checking validity of model in POST method). Form for "edit" operation is exact copy of form for adding student right now (to be sure i avoided any spelling mistakes in field ID's etc. so im not expecting problem there.

Where might be the problem? Put is working just fine when tested with Postman but i can't make it work with JS.

I would be gratefull for any help
Cheers

Comment: Why do you need `id` in `url` and in `data`?

Comment: I think, the posted data in editStudent does not fit to the Student class. Please provide the definition of the Student class and the JSON data from the Postman versus the sent JSON by your script. I bet there are some differences.

Comment: Try removing id from data in your second ajax call as you are already passing it via query parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `id` in body but in action method you expect only `Student` from body.

Change `data`in `ajax`:

```
data: $("#newStudent").serializeArray(), // pass only student
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem - but i thought if i have two arguments required in my put method i should give both parameters as 'data'. Im new to JS.

Comment: @macck, Yes, you have to. But you should add `[FromBody]` to the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you again, so assume i need to do pass both,     [FromBody] next to id should solve my problem also ?

Comment: Yes, but if you put `[FromBody]` before `id` then in ajax you should delete `id` from url.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use put?

Using put, you want to place/replace a specific resource on the server.
 The resource does not get found under this url and thus you get a bad request.

Basically the request does not get routed to your controller method at all.